# Wordpress editor shortcode for custom html ouput

Tags: php, wordpress

I need help creating Wordpress function to make shortcode `[youtube-id=ID]` in post editor output the following html code with `ID` value included:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ID?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your functions.php

```
function YouTubeID($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('id'=>''), $atts));
    return '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$id.'?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
}
add_shortcode('youtube', 'YouTubeID');
```

wherever you want the video the shortcode will be:

```
[youtube id="THE_ID"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function my_amazing_shortcode_handler($args)
{
    $args=shortcode_atts(array('id' => 'some_default_id'), $args);
    return '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $args['id'] . '?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
}

add_shortcode('youtube_iframe', 'my_amazing_shortcode_handler');
```

Use like `[youtube_iframe id='some_id']`

For reference: [add_shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/), [shortcode_atts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_atts/)